# Where should I store some of my project's parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, configuration

I don't know where should I store some of the parameters of my PHP/MySQL website, like number of entries per page, number of viewers of website and etc.
First I decided to store them in a MySQL table called for example parameter, but I think it is not a good approach because I realized that the settings and parameters of my website are just one entity and it is not standard to reserve a table for just one entity. What solutions do you think should I use?

Comment: Personally I'd use a JSON file, parsed in and out with `json_decode()` and `json_encode()` respectively, however if you ever make a per-user settings scheme, that should really go in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Use a configuration file. Inside you code your parameters in some serialized form. Might be JSON, but it is even easier if you use plain ini file syntax. That way you can modify the file more easily. Start by reading [php's ini file parsing method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is several solutions, one as you say is to store the parameters of you project in a table, for example Drupal do it that way, implementing two functions: `variable_get` and `variable_set` to retrieve and store the values of parameters.

Other frameworks use .ini or xml files. I like the use of YAML files, as Symfony do, because is a clear format and you can parse it easily.